# ASM Replace Certain Encoded Values

Tags: java, bytecode

I have been looking at how to edit jar files with ByteCode, the original values are encoded (which I have methods to decode so I can edit in eclipse.)  I then replace the decoded values back to the encoded values (I have methods to do this, which puts all the ByteCode into an array after the decoded values are re-encoded) after I export the new class file. Because I’m only editing 1 method at a time. I just need to open the original file class and put the edited version of the method into where the original one goes. How do I go about this?

Note: For example, a value I decode is: func_146528_d which equals, getLocalName(). I then edit the method, export. I then need to replace getLocalName to func_146528_d (with some code) and now I need to figure out how to replace that individual method in the old class file with my new re-encoded method (which is in an ArrayList.)

I’m using ASM 6.0 for all of this.

Comment: If you want to deobfuscate a Java program, I suggest, a) decompiling all the code, b) rename the methods in an IDE, c) compiling the code again. The reason this is a non-trivial is that the method `a` can appear many times with different signatures so renaming isn't simple.

Comment: Everything you said I already do. I already have everything working fine.  Instead of me copying and pasting the outputted re-encoded method back in manually (takes like 20 seconds with a ByteCode editor.) I want my program to do it for me.

Comment: You can do that, by visiting all the classes in your code base and replacing all the method calls which you want to rename. The hard part is working out when the rename or not if the method is overloaded.

Comment: ASM is really a low level toolkit. I advise you to prefer something on the line of ByteBuddy.

Comment: Why are you “only editing 1 method at a time”? You are trying to solve a problem that you have just created yourself.